# Tell grid not to cut my strings

Tags: extjs

I have a grid with thirty-two columns. The heading of each of the columns is one of Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa, Su.

If I make the cells smaller, it is at first `M..., Tu, W..., Th, Fr, Sa, Su`
which is obviously not useful, since `...` is at least as long as `o` in every font I know.

How can I disable this behaviour 
(a) for the grid header?
(b) for the grid table?

Comment: strange. I don't get that effect. Can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

columns: [
          {
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            dataIndex: 'string',
            text: 'Earning ID',
            flex: 1
          },
          ]

try using the flex this should fix the display